# Why do Chrome and Firefox handle javascript variable set inside jQuery ajax() callback differently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

Using jQuery 1.9.1, calling back to the server to check some data:

```
    $form = $("#form2")
    var str  = $form.serialize();
    status = true; 
    $.ajax({
           type    : 'POST',
           url     : 'check_zip.php', 
           data    : str,
           async   : false,
           success : function (data) {
             obj = JSON.parse(data); 
             var result = obj.result;
             status = result; 
           },
           error   : function (msg) {
               alert(msg);
               status = false;
           }
       });

    if (status == "false" || status === false) {
        ....
```

I found that Chrome would return status "false" (string) and Firefox would return status false (boolean).  Is this expected behavior?  I was astonished!

The JSON being parsed is data: "{"result":false}"

typeof(status) is string in Chrome and boolean in FF.

The issue  seems to arise here:

```
         var result = obj.result;
         status = result;
```

Because the datatype of result in Chrome is boolean, whereas the datatype of status is string.

[image: variable change shown in debugger]

Comment: What's the JSON it's parsing?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense the difference between `"false"` and `false` couldn't be bigger. They're absolutely not the same thing.

Comment: I hope you're not locking your users' browsers because you don't want to write asynchronous handling code.

Comment: It sounds like a difference in `JSON.parse` behavior between the 2 browsers. There are known to be differences in that code.

Comment: I am having trouble re producing that: JSON.parse("{\"result\":\"false\"}").result==="false"//true in chrome and FF JSON.parse("{\"result\":false}").result===false;// true in chrome and FF Using FF 20.0.1 on Win7 and Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: I typed `JSON.parse("false")` into the Javascript consoles of FF and Chrome and they both returned `false` rather than `"false"`.

Comment: What is the `Content-Type:` of the server response?

Comment: Try putting `console.log(data)` in both, to see if they're processing the response differently.

Comment: You could try using a library to parse them such as: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: Are you sure it's actually `false` and not undefined in ff? Could you post the output of `typeof status`?

Comment: Regarding your last edit: that can't be. Are you sure you're checking the value right on those two lines? There must be something else.

Comment: @bfavaretto see image showing this behavior in Chrome debugger.  If I'm lying, I'm dying.

Comment: I really hope you're not dying! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it.  The issue was the missing "var" before the declaration of status.

As @bfavaretto noted below, status is already defined as a global variable.  So if I had used a variable named like "ajax_status" I would have been fine without the var *or* I could have used the "status" variable name, but would have had to make it local (using var).

The following code works like a champ in both FF and Chrome.

```
$form = $("#form2")
var str  = $form.serialize();
var status = true;                 // <--- change 1 - use "var" 
$.ajax({
       type    : 'POST',
       url     : 'check_zip.php', 
       data    : str,
       async   : false,
       success : function (data) {
         obj = JSON.parse(data); 
         var result = obj.result;
         status = result; 
       },
       error   : function (msg) {
           alert(msg);
           status = false;
       }
   });

if (status === false) {        // <-- change 2 - just use boolean comparison
   ...
```

Another way to code this would be

```
    var ajaxreturn = $.ajax({
           type    : 'POST',
           url     : 'check_zip.php', 
           data    : str,
           async   : false,
           success : function (data) {
           },
           error   : function (msg) {
              alert("Unexpected server response on zip validation"); 
           }
       });

    var status = false; 
    try { 
       obj = JSON.parse(ajaxreturn.responseText); 
       status = obj.result; 
    } catch (e) { 
      status = false;
    }

    if (status === false) { 
       ...
```

and probably the best practice would be not to reuse the existing variable name status, so using the second example, this would give

```
    var ajaxreturn = $.ajax({
           type    : 'POST',
           url     : 'check_zip.php', 
           data    : str,
           async   : false,
           success : function (data) {
           },
           error   : function (msg) {
              alert("Unexpected server response on zip validation"); 
           }
       });

    var check_status = false; 
    try { 
       obj = JSON.parse(ajaxreturn.responseText); 
       check_status = obj.result; 
    } catch (e) { 
      check_status = false;
    }

    if (check_status === false) { 
       ...
```

Comment: `status` was a global variable, and one that exists by default in a browser environment (check `window.status`, it's used to set the statusbar text). I'm guessing it's actually a setter in Chrome, and the setter code was probably auto converting it to a string.

Comment: Funny to see this was the problem, and I agree with @bfavaretto that it was probably the statusbar property that is always a string by definition causing this.

Comment: @bfavaretto This was the root cause; I have updated my answer.

Comment: @bfavaretto I'd be happy to give you the points if you'd like to make your comment into an answer.

Comment: Thank you Scott, but your answer already contains all the information needed to help future visitors. I was curious about what could be causing this issue, I'm glad you added this answer to clarify that. Also, I believe you should mark this answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, there must be something else going wrong. In Chrome, the string `{"result":"false"}` is correctly received, parsed, and shown that it contains the string `false`. On Firefox, your XHR call appears to fail for some unidentified reason,, the `error` handler is invoked, where you yourself explicitly execute `status = false`, thus resulting in it outputting the boolean `false`. Whilst this is the only logical explanation for the different data type, it does not explain why the `alert` call wouldn't be showing an error box. It could be that you checked the "Do not allow this page to create more dialogs" box during earlier testing? I'm curious what the output in FF is when you change that errorhandler line to `status = 684` instead of `false`.

We would need a reproducible case somewhere to dive into this further, all other comments have indicated that FF and Chrome parse the JSON identically.

Comment: The errorhandler isn't called because the alert doesn't show up.  I can trace the code in Firebug and watch it go through the success path.